# How to remove top and bottom whitespace of longtable?

Tags: tables, spacing, longtable

I am using `longtable` instead of `tabular` environment and noticed that it puts some additional whitespace at the top and at the bottom of the table. Is there some way to remove it (something less hacky than `\vskip -\baselineskip` before the table)?

Small piece of code for illustration:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

Linelineline

\begin{longtable}{l l} cell1 & cell2 \end{longtable}

Linelineline

\begin{tabular}{l l} cell1 & cell2 \end{tabular}

Linelineline

\end{document}
```

And that's what I am getting:

[image: tables]

Common `tabular` environment does not have any additional margins, but `longtable` does.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To remove the whitespace before and after a longtable, you may change the lengths `\LTpre` and `\LTpost`:

```
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
```

Their default value is `\bigskipamount`.

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks. May I also ask what I have to write to get rid of the top and bottom space when using enumerate?

Comment: What I needed was actually `\setlength{\LTpre}{15pt}` and `\setlength{\LTpost}{-5pt}`, but perhaps that’s due to my usage of `ltablex` instead of `longtable` (which is based on the latter, though) and a different document class. When using `\the`, both were reported as `12.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 4.0pt`, though. Strange.