# How to decrease sep between longtable and text

Tags: longtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove top and bottom whitespace of longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/how-to-remove-top-and-bottom-whitespace-of-longtable)

code like this

```
Maintext

\begin{longtable}{c}
    tabletext
\end{longtable}

Maintext
```

please tell me how to decrease the vetical space between `Maintext` and `tabletext`.

--EDIT--
I have found the answer: [How to remove top and bottom whitespace of longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/how-to-remove-top-and-bottom-whitespace-of-longtable). Thanks this website.