# Big space between longtable/longtabu and the preceeding section header

Tags: spacing, longtable, longtabu

If I add a `longtable` or `longtabu` environment directly after a `\section` command a very big space is set between the header and the table. In case of the second example where some text is in between these two elements, that's no problem. But in the other cases the big space bothers me. Anyhow, with a regular `tabular`-environment this problem does not occur.

I already tried to use things like `\raggedbottom`. A `\vspace{-1em}` solves the problem, but that seems like a very sloppy solution to me.

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of that space?

**EDIT:**
After another round of extensive search and studying the log file, I was able to figure it out: the space is specified by `\LTpre` and adding `\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}` resulted in the desired output.
Afterwards I found a previous question about the same problem: [How to remove top and bottom whitespace of longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/how-to-remove-top-and-bottom-whitespace-of-longtable)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}  
\begin{document}
\section{First section with longtabu}
\begin{longtabu} {rX}
    cell1-1 & cell1-2\\\\
    cell2-1 & cell2-2\\\\
\end{longtabu}  
\section{Second section with longtabu}
Some text prior to the table
\begin{longtabu} {rX}
    cell1-1 & cell1-2\\\\
    cell2-1 & cell2-2\\\\
\end{longtabu}  
\section{Another section with longtable}
\begin{longtable}[l]{rl}
    cell1-1 & cell1-2\\\\
    cell2-1 & cell2-2\\\\
\end{longtable}  
\section{Last section with tabular}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    cell1-1 & cell1-2\\\\
    cell2-1 & cell2-2\\\\
\end{tabular}  
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]