# How to remove top and bottom whitespace of longtblr?

Tags: longtable, white-space, longtblr

Similarly to [How to remove top and bottom whitespace of longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/how-to-remove-top-and-bottom-whitespace-of-longtable), I would like to know how to remove top and bottom whitespace of longtblr, i.e. the whitespace between the text (both before and after) and the longtblr (unless `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}`, or something similar, is the only way). This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|},hlines}
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
\end{longtblr}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried the same workaround as in the above mentioned question related to "longtable", i.e. to add `\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt} \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}`, but it does not work and I get the error `Undefined control sequence`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|},hlines}
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
\end{longtblr}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `presep` and `postsep` options to change the space above and below the `longtblr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}[presep=0pt,postsep=0pt]{ colspec = {|X|X|},hlines}
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
First variable & Second variable \\
\end{longtblr}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! A great solution! :-)

Comment: @Ommo You're welcome!